# Finding most significant bit in linux

Tags: linux, shell

I am working on raspberry pi, for the command :

```
char-write-req 0x0011 e00000e0
```

I am getting `ouput1` as:

```
12 57 7e 35 2d 49
```

Similarly,

```
char-write-req 0x0011 e00100e1
```

`output2` is:

```
23 45 76 3e 66 2d
```

In a similar way I am getting output for different commands, now I want to check for MSB and pass that bit in switch case i.e I want "1" from 12 of `ouput1` and "2" from 23 of `output2` and generate a switch case for that.
How can i do this?

Comment: You want a bit or the first digit?

Comment: @krzyk first digit ..as i said..1 from 12.

Answer (score 1):

Use `cut -c 1` to get the first character from the output:

```
char-write-req 0x0011 e00000e0 | cut -c 1
```

For the case you use:

```
case `char-write-req 0x0011 e00000e0 | cut -c 1` in                               
    1) echo "something" ;;                                                      
    2) echo "something else" ;;                                                 
esac
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply..now first digit is not fixed it keeps on changing..so i want such that it checks for digit position..say if first position contains 1 it should fire e00100e1 ,if first contains  5 then it should fire e00500e5 and so on..

Comment: @user3484325 added